# ‘abstract method not implemented’ on start android app with Crashlytics (Fabric)

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, crashlytics

I added Crashlytics to my android app (via Idea plugin).

When my app starts I get next error:

```
 java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.ActivityLifecycleManager$ActivityLifecycleCallbacksWrapper$1.onActivityStarted(ActivityLifecycleManager.java)
        at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityStarted(Application.java:199)
        at android.app.Activity.onStart(Activity.java:1048)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:536)
```

I completely can't figure out why this happens. Maybe someone faced with this issue?

Comment: You claim to implement an Interface but haven't implemented one of its methods.  Since that wouldn't normally get through the compiler, I'd suspect either a version mismatch between what you developed against and what is on the device, or else proguard stripping out something it isn't able to discern as being used, which you could fix with configuration.

Comment: Yes it's right. Main issue here that this error happens in the 'Fabric' code, probably you're right that proguard stripping out something in it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above (by Chris), proguard stripping out something it isn't able to discern as being used. And it really stripping Crashlytics/Fabric classes.
For avoid this, just need add these lines to proguard config file:

```
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }   
-keep class io.fabric.** { *; } 
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
```